# When to use ".ensure_lookup_table()"?

Tags: python, bmesh

For modifying meshes (in the hereunder example removing vertices), I use the script as follows:

```
        # Création du Bmesh
        maillage = bpy.data.meshes[nom_objet]
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(maillage)
        # Mise à jour des ID des listes verts et faces
        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        # Suppression de tous les points du maillage sur Ox
        points_a_supprimer = [v for v in bm.verts if v.co.yz.length < 1e-07]
        bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom = points_a_supprimer, context = 'VERTS')
        # Modification du maillage de l'objet et suppression du Bmesh
        bm.to_mesh(maillage)
        bm.free()
        del bm
```

But I do not really understand if the use of ".ensure_lookup_table()" is relevant. What is the purpose of this code ?
Thanks in advance for explanations.

Comment: Totally unnecessary here. Relevant when indexing eg `v = bm.verts[0]`.   Recommend testing against a tollerance rather than exact values.  eg `v.co.xy.length < 1e-7`

Comment: [Ensure lookup table](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVertSeq.ensure_lookup_table) only needed after you change the `BMVertSeq` in your script

Comment: Thanks !Removing vertices does not change the BMVertSeq ?

Comment: It does but as previously mentioned only relevant if you are indexing elements in some manner before writing back to mesh, and / or freeing.  For most cases the enumerated elements matches the index order, but to be _sure to be sure_ run the ensure for that element type  before doing so.  If you do try indexing without ensure lookup table  will get an error that you need to run ensure lookup table prior, indicating where and when to use.  For example script in question it is not required,  perhaps queston could be re-titled  _When_ not _How_

Comment: @HikariTW see above. Always  needed if you intend to index that element.  _eg_ in console try `bm = bmesh.new()` and follow with `bm.verts[0]` ..... error need to run ensure lookup table. .. remember this is an empty new bmesh so no sequence has been altered.

Comment: @batFINGER , when I remove the code line "bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()" from the script, it continuous working right. And after that, if I add the code line "v=bm.verts[0]" I get the error message "IndexError: BMElemSeq[index]: outdated internal index table, run ensure_lookup_table() first". So, things are now clear for me. Again thanks for help.