# How to obtain a vertex list from select_non_manifold()

Tags: python, scripting

I don't understand why the `vlist` is empty after execution. I can visually see that several vertices were selected, if I use the 3d Viewport equivalent of `bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()`  in *Edit Mode* which is *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold* before running the script (it lists the proper vertices that *I* select through the UI, but not on its own).

```
o=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
m = bmesh.new()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
m.from_mesh(o.data)
m.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

vlist=[]
for v in m.verts:
    if v.select:
        vlist.append(v)
print(vlist)
```

Comment: That's actually a good point. Apparently we have to do `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')` after selection and then you can optionally get  back into *Edit Mode* if you need by to using `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` but not necessary. Maybe that's exactly what *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold* does.

Comment: Using bmesh you can get the non-manifolds by `item.is_manifold` [BMVERT](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.is_manifold) regardless of the previously selection. Change `if v.select:` to `if not v.is_manifold:`. No need for _bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()_ anymore but it doesn´t trouble.

Comment: @relaxed -- oddly, all verts are reported as is_manifold (True), including those that aren't!  Scratching me head here....

Comment: I assume that you have made changes in _editmode_ and ran code without toggling to _objectmode_. Changes have not passed to o.data when bmesh is created from object. Try `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')` in first line of script for updating, or remove `m = bmesh.new()` and `m.from_mesh(o.data)` and insert `m = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(o.data)` below editmode line to get bmesh from object in editmode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a clean version of the comments above

```
import bpy
import bmesh

o=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
m = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(o.data)

m.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
vlist=[]
for v in m.verts:
    if not v.is_manifold:
        vlist.append(v)
print(vlist)
```

Comment: I don't know why is_manifold is broken.  My output: ```[]```

Comment: A mystery to me. Just tested in 2.93.7, 3.3.2 and 3.4.1 (Window) and it´s fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Blender [ApI documentations](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.4/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.from_mesh) says that

> from_mesh(mesh)
> Initialize this bmesh from existing mesh datablock.

> bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh):
> Return a BMesh from this mesh, currently the mesh must already be in editmode.

So the cause is that your script is using unedited mesh data.

```
o=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
m = bmesh.new()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()


m.from_mesh(o.data)
m.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

vlist=[]
for v in m.verts:
    if v.select:
        vlist.append(v)
print(vlist)

m.free()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `ensure_lookup_table()` call, which is only needed [if the `BMVertSeq` changes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190290/when-to-use-ensure-lookup-table). Apparently the selection doesn't update until you change back to *Object Mode* after the selection with `bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()` by doing `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`. Also you have to be careful because you are only appending the reference of the pointers to the vertices which are only temporary and get disposed after `bmesh.free()` is called. So it is best you store the vertex indices, which you can then use to easily access any vertex at any time using `bpy.context.object.data.vertices[index]`.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

o=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
m = bmesh.new()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
m.from_mesh(o.data)
m.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

vlist=[]
for v in m.verts:
    if v.select:
        vlist.append(v.index)
print(vlist)

m.free()
```

Comment: Back an forth between modes and throw salt over my shoulder.  That's my arcane blender!

Comment: hahaha i like markus answer! we learn everyday :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to toggle Edit/Object mode:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C

me = C.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
print([v.index for v in bm.verts if v.select])
```

Comment: and perhaps ```bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')``` instead of the for loop?